# Woocommerce, different order emails depending on product in order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to send two different "new_order" emails depending on the products ordered.
The case is that the products are stored at different locations and I need one email to be sent containing only the products present at storage 1, and the other mail containing the products present at storage 2.
If only products located at storage 1 was ordered, email 2 should not be sent at all, and vice versa.

The storage information is a custom meta field on each product.

I have added a custom email-class which is a copy of `class-wc-email-new-order` but only with changed name where needed.

I've been looking through the hooks and filters for this, but I was not able to go all the way. I've also been thinking about overriding the `email-order-details.php`file and check each products meta field, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go. I guess the email would still be sent even if there are no products in the table, so to speak.

My problem is that I don't know which of the emails are sent out when using the different filters, so I cannot check that condition either.

Would you just create two new emails with templates and everything and go that way, or is it something I'm missing here?

If I can clarify anything, please let me know.

Edit: After talking a bit with @helgatheviking I realized that I needed to clearify that the emails regarding storage 1 should be sent only when the order contained products located at storage 1 and emails regarding storage 2 should only be sent when the order contained products located at storage 2.
If the order contained both kind of products, both emails should be sent, but only displaying their respective products.

Comment: You could duplicate the customer processing order email and then customize the [`trigger()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-processing-order.php#L49) method since you'd have access to the `$order` object and could check if the required products were ordered.

Comment: @helgatheviking hey Helga and thank you for your reply. :) I was actually looking at the trigger method, but I did not see how I could create a new order object. If I check for my products in storage 2, and send the order object further, all products would still be added into the email, correct?

Comment: @helgatheviking I managed to do it by overriding email-order-details.php and checking which email was being sent and filter the products from that.
However, storage2 is getting two emails atm and I feel kind of dirty for doing it this hacky way... :D

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you look the `trigger()` method in the code that I linked you to, you will see that the `$order_id` is the first parameter and is always passed. the `$order` object is possibly there as the second parameter. As they do in the WooCommerce `trigger()` you can test for the presence of `$order` and if it doesn't exist then you can get the object from the ID which is guaranteed to be there. `$order=wc_get_order($order_id)`.

Comment: @helgatheviking exactly, but if I have an order with both product types present, I would still have to do my template hack, or I would still get all products in the mail I guess?
I mean, I cannot remove order items from an order when the order is created, can I?
I only want products from storage 1 in the Woo-email and the products from storage 2 in my custom email. :)

Comment: So now you need to know how to only list certain items in the particular emails? That's not part of the original question. Please edit the question for completeness.... and also include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @helgatheviking ah I thought I did try to explain that, but you are probably right. I'll edit and add code tomorrow (as it is getting late here). Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: @helgatheviking sorry to disturb, but you dont happen to have any solutions at hand regarding the problem I am having using the method below? Two emails are sent out for every order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585824/woocommerce-custom-email-classes-creates-duplicate-emails

Comment: @helgatheviking found the error myself, thank you for your help earlier! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After thinking it through and reflecting upon what @helgatheviking said I was able to come up with a solution.

I copied the `class-wc-new-order` and created two new classes exactly the same as the original.
I changed ID and class names to storage 1 and storage 2 respectively.

I load the classes by doing the following: **EDIT WRONG METHOD, SEE BELOW INSTEAD**

```
//Add our custom class to WC email classes
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', [ $this, 'custom_order_email_add_email_classes' ], 10, 1 );

function custom_order_email_add_email_classes( $email_classes ) {

     require( CUSTOM_ORDER_EMAIL_PLUGIN_DIR . 'classes/class-wc-email-new-order-storage1.php' );
     require( CUSTOM_ORDER_EMAIL_PLUGIN_DIR . 'classes/class-wc-email-new-order-storage2.php' );

     $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Storage1']  = new WC_Email_New_Order_Storage1(); 
     $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Storage2']  = new WC_Email_New_Order_Storage2();

     return $email_classes;
}
```

Notice that this is within a special plugin, you'll have to edit the code a bit if you were to use it in your functions.php.

I then edited the `trigger()`-function in both email classes:

```
public function trigger( $order_id, $order = false ) {

    $trigger = false;

    if ( $order_id && ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $this->object                  = $order;
        $this->find['order-date']      = '{order_date}';
        $this->find['order-number']    = '{order_number}';
        $this->replace['order-date']   = wc_format_datetime( $this->object->get_date_created() );
        $this->replace['order-number'] = $this->object->get_order_number();

        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {

            $product = $item->get_product();

            if ( $product->get_meta( '_product_storage' ) == 'storage2' ) {//storage1 in the other email class
                $trigger = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $trigger === true) {
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be behaving as it should but I'll do some more testing before accepting my own answer.
Thanks again to Helgatheviking for leading me onto the right track. :)

Edit: forgot to add my override of `email-order-details.php`.
This is added just below `<tbody>`

```
if ( $email->id == 'new_order_storage1' ) {

        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) {

            $product = $item->get_product();

            if ( $product->get_meta( '_product_storage' ) == 'storage1' ) {
        ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

                        // Show title/image etc
                        if ( $show_image ) {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' ) ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Product image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-' . ( is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right' ) . ': 10px;" /></div>', $item );
                        }

                        // Product name
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false );

                        // SKU
                        if ( $show_sku && is_object( $product ) && $product->get_sku() ) {
                            echo ' (#' . $product->get_sku() . ')';
                        }

                        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

                        wc_display_item_meta( $item );

                        if ( $show_download_links ) {
                            wc_display_item_downloads( $item );
                        }

                        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

                    ?></td>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ); ?></td>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( $email->id == 'new_order_storage2' ) {
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) {

            $product = $item->get_product();

            if ( $product->get_meta( '_product_storage' ) == 'storage2' ) {
        ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

                        // Show title/image etc
                        if ( $show_image ) {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' ) ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Product image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-' . ( is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right' ) . ': 10px;" /></div>', $item );
                        }

                        // Product name
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false );

                        // SKU
                        if ( $show_sku && is_object( $product ) && $product->get_sku() ) {
                            echo ' (#' . $product->get_sku() . ')';
                        }

                        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

                        wc_display_item_meta( $item );

                        if ( $show_download_links ) {
                            wc_display_item_downloads( $item );
                        }

                        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

                    ?></td>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ); ?></td>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    else {
     echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
        'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
        'show_image'    => false,
        'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
        'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
    ) ); 
    }
```

The code displaying order items are taken directly from `order-email-items`.
I am not sure if there is a better way to do this thought, feel free to correct me if this is the case.

**EDIT**, Skyverge was using an old method to load custom email classes.
Correct method for loading custom email classes is:

```
    //Add our custom class to WC email classes
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', [ $this, 'custom_order_email_add_email_classes' ], 10, 1 );

    function custom_order_email_add_email_classes( $email_classes ) {

         $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Storage1']  = include( CUSTOM_ORDER_EMAIL_PLUGIN_DIR . 'classes/class-wc-email-new-order-storage1.php' );
         $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Storage2']  = include( CUSTOM_ORDER_EMAIL_PLUGIN_DIR . 'classes/class-wc-email-new-order-storage2.php' );

     return $email_classes;
}
```

Comment: I implemented this exactly as suggested above, but now in the WordPress Dashboard under Woocommerce > Settings > Emails it no longer displays the list of notification email types or lets you manage which email addresses are notified. Any suggestions?

Comment: So basically its not working as intended. One difference is that I'm using Woocommerce Version 3.5.7 in 2019 and I see your post is from 2017...

Comment: If I comment out the woocommerce_email_classes in functions.php I can adjust the Email Settings again, but anytime I enable that code to add the custom email classes it breaks the Woocommerce Email Settings from within the WordPress Dashboard. Weird thing is I'm not getting any error messages at all, I just simply can no longer adjust Email Settings.

Comment: This is my code:
```
  function custom_order_email_add_email_classes( $email_classes ) {
    $plugin_dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/';
    $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Location1']  = include( $plugin_dir . 'class-wc-email-new-order-location1.php' );
    $email_classes['WC_Email_New_Order_Location2']  = include( $plugin_dir . 'class-wc-email-new-order-location2.php' );
    return $email_classes;
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', [ $this, 'custom_order_email_add_email_classes' ], 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hey @JGrover, saw this now.
The site using this is running Woo 3.4.3 still, so perhaps there has been some changes made to Woo emails since then.
You could perhaps look through the changes made in 3.5 or so, I am not able to try this myself right now I am afraid. I will note it down and take a look though, but I might not be able to do so before the weekend.

Comment: thanks for reply back, just FYI I discovered how to do this by using a woocommerce hook inside functions.php which makes it unneccesary to create your own email classes. See: https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/customising-woocommerce-notification-emails-hooks-filters/

Comment: @JGrover hey, ah great that you solved it. My weekend did not turn out as I thought it would so I have not had the opportunity to investigate this further, but I'll try to do that when I have the time and get back here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize them like this: https://www.sellwithwp.com/customizing-woocommerce-order-emails/

Var_dump that $order object but I bet you have access to the Product ID which you can then use to figure out which storage it belongs to and adjust the email content accordingly.

Comment: Hej @samyer and thank you. I did look through that already, I did not quite find what I need however.